# Why is setState not working in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a question about setting the state, why does it work directly in the the componentDidMount function but when calling it in the setInterval it doesn't work...

I appreciate your help!

Here my code:

```
class TemperaturePaper extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const {sensorName} = props;

        this.state = {
            temperature: 0,
            status: ''
        };
    }

    getTemperatureFromSensor = (sensorName) => {
        //const response = getTemperatureFormSensor(sensorName);
        console.log('fff');
        this.setState({temperature: 50, status: 'response.data.status'});
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => getTemperatureFormSensor('rtd1'), 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }


    render() {
        const {classes} = this.props;

        return (
            <Paper className={classes.cardWrapper}>
                <Typography className={classes.cardSubtitle} variant={'subtitle1'}>Akt. Temperatur</Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.cardHeader} variant={'h1'}>{this.state.temperature} °C</Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.cardFootertitle} variant={'subtitle1'}>Sensor-Status: {this.state.status}</Typography>
            </Paper>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `() =>`   arrow function loose `this`, so don't use an arrow function, and also bind your callback functions to keep `this`.    Remember `() => {}` is not a shortened form of `function {}`

Comment: Ok, sorry for asking again, what would be the right way to do it? If I delete the () = ? -> this.getTemperatureFromSensor() is not a function, altough I turned this to getTemperatureFromSensor () {}...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember arrow functions don't have a `this`,  the `this` is only what's in the current scope.

So 2 things you need to do.

1. change `getTemperatureFromSensor = (sensorName) => {` to `getTemperatureFromSensor (sensorName) {`
2. bind the function in your constructor do -> `this.getTemperatureFromSensor = this.getTemperatureFromSensor.bind(this)`

No 1. means the function has it's own this, that arrow functions don't get.

No 2, makes sure the `this` inside the function is now bound to the object.  In Javascript passing a method doesn't also pass the object, like in other languages.

Another option.

1. Still do Option 1 from above, as we still need the `this`.
2. Alter the the setInterval to -> `this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getTemperatureFromSensor('rtd1'), 1000);`

Basically using the arrow function on the `this.interval =` just avoids us having to bind.

Comment: First, I need to say thank you for your support and help! I changed all the points you mentioned and I get an error: TypeError: this.getTemperatureFormSensor is not a function... Have I forgot something?

Comment: @pkdev97   You appear to have put -> `getTemperatureFormSensor` and not `getTemperatureFromSensor`  , ps.  that was my fault, if you copy pasted :)